# Latex produce side by side boxes with same height and width

Tags: pdftex, minipage

I want to produce same height and width boxes side by side with text inside as

Expected output:

[image]

My solution:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}

\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{white}
{\minipage[t]
  {\dimexpr0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \centering
  Product1 demo
 \endminipage
}\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{white}
{\minipage[t]
  {\dimexpr0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \centering
 France\\
Newyork\\
Japan\\
London
 \endminipage
}\hfill
```

Present output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment with an overall width of `\textwidth`.

[image]

The optional `\Tstrut` ("top strut") directives are there to keep the "France" and "Sydney" rows from being placed too close to horizontal lines above them.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}      % horizontal centering
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}  % "top" typographic strut (optional)

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| >{\bfseries}C | C |} % typeset 1st column in **bold**
\hline
Product 1 demo & 
  France\Tstrut \newline New York \newline Japan \newline London \\
\hline\hline
Product 2 demo &
  Sydney\Tstrut \newline New York \newline Japan \newline London \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I create a `\newline` above France? so, I can get a clear space with box border.

Comment: Also, how to get a two-line space between Newyork and Japan?

Comment: @Mainland: On your first question: To get more vertical clearance, just increase the value of the final argument of `\Tstrut`. E.g., replace `\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}` with `\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{5ex}}`. To get a full blank line between "New York" and "Japan", replace `\newline` with `\newline\phantom{X}\newline`.

Comment: Simply perfect solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with boxes. First I measure the total vertical size of the second box and use it to set the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\demo}[3][\textwidth]{%
  % #1 is the desired total width
  % #2 is the text on the left
  % #3 is the text on the right
  \par\noindent
  \sbox0{\parbox{#1}{#3}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimen0]{\dimexpr(#1-4\fboxsep-3\fboxrule)/2}{\centering #2}%
  }\kern-\fboxrule
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr(#1-4\fboxsep-3\fboxrule)/2}{\centering #3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\demo{Product1 demo}{
  France\\
  Newyork\\
  Japan\\
  London
}

\vspace{2pt}

\demo{Product2 demo}{
  Sydney\\
  New York\\
  Japan\\
  London
}

\bigskip

\demo[0.5\textwidth]{Product1 demo}{
  France\\
  Newyork\\
  Japan\\
  London
}

\bigskip

\demo[0.75\textwidth]{Product2 demo}{
  Sydney\\
  New York\\
  Japan\\
  London
}

\end{document}
```

[image]